# Use ZipFile of 4.5 in 3.5 solutions

Tags: .net

Is there any way to import ZipFile class (System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll in .NET 4.5) in solution in .NET 3.5?
- Downloading the dll and adding it in reference will work ?

Comment: Have you tried adding it as a reference and seeing what happens?

Comment: I will be doing in today by EOD but in the meantime checking with you guys if it is possible... I will surely update with my findings...

Comment: Depends on its dependencies and it will not be supported (i.e. it can break with any update). Why not use a third-party library like [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) or [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/)?

Comment: That is the restriction I have... i cannot use any third party library eventhough it is free !! There is a option to use Shell32 dll... but I am more interested in the System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll because if it somehow works with me then if I upgrade the application to 4.5 later on i donot have to bother about this.

Comment: I tried it out... i got got compile time error saying incomtability !! Logically true due to strong name types..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zip is a standard for compression, it does not matter how you have compressed the file. Any other program that supports zip will be able to decompress your file. If you compress with System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll from .net 4.5 you can decompress with any libary for zip support which is supported in 3.5. Have a look at DotNetZip or SharpZipLib.